# What is the difference between port vs rpc-port?

Tags: substrate-node-template, substrate-parachain-template

While starting node, what is the difference between `--port` and `--rpc-port`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running your node with `--help` will show you all the flags with a quick definition: `./target/release/node-template --help`

```sh
--rpc-port <PORT>.  //Specify JSON-RPC server TCP port

--port <PORT> //Specify p2p protocol TCP port
```

In this case `--port` specifies the port to listen on for peer-to-peer (p2p) traffic (for the nodes to connect) and `--rpc-port` specifies the port to listen on for incoming RPC traffic (for frontend to connect with the node).